# .htaccess rewrite subdomain to domain for all image

Tags: image, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My domain: example.com

SubDomain: admin.example.com

I want to rewrite all image url like:

```
admin.example.com/img/image1.jpg -> example.com/img/image1.jpg
admin.example.com/img/image2.png -> example.com/img/image2.png
admin.example.com/img/image3.gif -> example.com/img/image3.gif
```

This is my `.htaccess` but it does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|ico|bmp)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^admin.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|ico|bmp)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Confirmed at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /img/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/img/%1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank to Starkeen, it work. But may be catch for only file, not folder img?

Comment: Yes ,it only captures the files as **%1** for reuse in rewrite target.