# htaccess - point all images from subfolder to subdomain (without redirect)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Want to point in my .htaccess all requests from `site.com/img/any_image.jpg` to >> `img.site.com/img/any_image.jpg` **without a redirect**.

So in other words, users and all requests must go to **site.com/img/any_image.jpg**, but eventually, content is gathered from a subdomain.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Lol! Posted my question and found this answer - [.htaccess rewrite subdomain to domain for all image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283030/htaccess-rewrite-subdomain-to-domain-for-all-image)

But had to adapt it vise versa to satisfy my needs:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /img/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://img.site.com/img/%1 [NC,R=302,L]
```

R=302 - for testing

R=301 - for live production

Works as expected!

Comment: Also LOL, because that of course _is_ a redirect, which you said you didn't want.

Comment: @CBroe, well, yes, it does. Do you know the right mrthod then?

Comment: Depends on the details of the setup, whether you can just rewrite into the matching directory. If not, then you would need to _proxy_ the request (see: mod_proxy, `P` flag of RewriteRule.)